# Webserver Code flow

Tags: go

I am creating a simple web server using Go using net/HTTP package.
The simple code is like this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)
type hotdog int
func (m hotdog) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Any code you want in this func")
}
func main() {
    var d hotdog
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", d)
}
```

So, I want to know what is happening under the hood?
If I am not wrong

ListenAndServe() takes the address and handler and this function runs inside the library

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error {
    server := &Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    return server.ListenAndServe()
  }
```

and after this function calls the ListenAndServe

```
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error {
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
  }
```

Now the Serve Function is called. But I am not able to understand how this parameter (`tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)}`) is converted to 
 (`l net.Listener`) in Serve Function

```
func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {
    defer l.Close()
    if fn := testHookServerServe; fn != nil {
        fn(srv, l)
    }
    var tempDelay time.Duration // how long to sleep on accept failure

    if err := srv.setupHTTP2_Serve(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    srv.trackListener(l, true)
    defer srv.trackListener(l, false)

    baseCtx := context.Background() // base is always background, per Issue 16220
    ctx := context.WithValue(baseCtx, ServerContextKey, srv)
    for {
        rw, e := l.Accept()
        if e != nil {
            select {
            case <-srv.getDoneChan():
                return ErrServerClosed
            default:
            }
            if ne, ok := e.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
                if tempDelay == 0 {
                    tempDelay = 5 * time.Millisecond
                } else {
                    tempDelay *= 2
                }
                if max := 1 * time.Second; tempDelay > max {
                    tempDelay = max
                }
                srv.logf("http: Accept error: %v; retrying in %v", e, tempDelay)
                time.Sleep(tempDelay)
                continue
            }
            return e
        }
        tempDelay = 0
        c := srv.newConn(rw)
        c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
        go c.serve(ctx)
    }
  }
```

**Where is the handler called?**

Comment: `tcpKeepAliveListener` _is_  a `net.Listener`. You have to follow the code further to find where the handlers are called.

Comment: Indeed - more specifically, `net.Listener` is an interface, and `tcpKeepAliveListener` fulfills that interface.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate this line tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)}  tcsKeepAlive is of type struct so we are initializing that here but how is this thing working   {ln.(*net.TCPListener)}

Comment: @kartik: can you be more specific than "how is this thing working?"? The `ln` returned by `net.Listen` is a `*net.TCPListener`, and it's being asserted as such to use in the `tcpKeepAliveListener`

Comment: @kartik maybe this can clear it up a bit: https://play.golang.org/p/CrlRN6NpLRd

Comment: @kartik here's a bit more info to answer the subsequent question that was removed https://play.golang.org/p/btvyCrdzrnO

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they've already commented, the `net.Listener` type is an interface, and `tcpKeepAliveListener` satisfies that interface, so the type is correct.

Then, to answer your question about where is the Handler called, you need to go deeper in the code flow:

The line `go c.serve(ctx)` from the last piece of code you posted, is calling `conn.serve()`:

```
// Serve a new connection.
func (c *conn) serve(ctx context.Context) {
    c.remoteAddr = c.rwc.RemoteAddr().String()
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil && err != ErrAbortHandler {
            const size = 64 << 10
            buf := make([]byte, size)
            buf = buf[:runtime.Stack(buf, false)]
            c.server.logf("http: panic serving %v: %v\n%s", c.remoteAddr, err, buf)
        }
        if !c.hijacked() {
            c.close()
            c.setState(c.rwc, StateClosed)
        }
    }()

    if tlsConn, ok := c.rwc.(*tls.Conn); ok {
        if d := c.server.ReadTimeout; d != 0 {
            c.rwc.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(d))
        }
        if d := c.server.WriteTimeout; d != 0 {
            c.rwc.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(d))
        }
        if err := tlsConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
            c.server.logf("http: TLS handshake error from %s: %v", c.rwc.RemoteAddr(), err)
            return
        }
        c.tlsState = new(tls.ConnectionState)
        *c.tlsState = tlsConn.ConnectionState()
        if proto := c.tlsState.NegotiatedProtocol; validNPN(proto) {
            if fn := c.server.TLSNextProto[proto]; fn != nil {
                h := initNPNRequest{tlsConn, serverHandler{c.server}}
                fn(c.server, tlsConn, h)
            }
            return
        }
    }

    // HTTP/1.x from here on.

    ctx, cancelCtx := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    c.cancelCtx = cancelCtx
    defer cancelCtx()

    c.r = &connReader{conn: c}
    c.bufr = newBufioReader(c.r)
    c.bufw = newBufioWriterSize(checkConnErrorWriter{c}, 4<<10)

    for {
        w, err := c.readRequest(ctx)
        if c.r.remain != c.server.initialReadLimitSize() {
            // If we read any bytes off the wire, we're active.
            c.setState(c.rwc, StateActive)
        }
        if err != nil {
            const errorHeaders = "\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"

            if err == errTooLarge {
                // Their HTTP client may or may not be
                // able to read this if we're
                // responding to them and hanging up
                // while they're still writing their
                // request. Undefined behavior.
                const publicErr = "431 Request Header Fields Too Large"
                fmt.Fprintf(c.rwc, "HTTP/1.1 "+publicErr+errorHeaders+publicErr)
                c.closeWriteAndWait()
                return
            }
            if isCommonNetReadError(err) {
                return // don't reply
            }

            publicErr := "400 Bad Request"
            if v, ok := err.(badRequestError); ok {
                publicErr = publicErr + ": " + string(v)
            }

            fmt.Fprintf(c.rwc, "HTTP/1.1 "+publicErr+errorHeaders+publicErr)
            return
        }

        // Expect 100 Continue support
        req := w.req
        if req.expectsContinue() {
            if req.ProtoAtLeast(1, 1) && req.ContentLength != 0 {
                // Wrap the Body reader with one that replies on the connection
                req.Body = &expectContinueReader{readCloser: req.Body, resp: w}
            }
        } else if req.Header.get("Expect") != "" {
            w.sendExpectationFailed()
            return
        }

        c.curReq.Store(w)

        if requestBodyRemains(req.Body) {
            registerOnHitEOF(req.Body, w.conn.r.startBackgroundRead)
        } else {
            if w.conn.bufr.Buffered() > 0 {
                w.conn.r.closeNotifyFromPipelinedRequest()
            }
            w.conn.r.startBackgroundRead()
        }

        // HTTP cannot have multiple simultaneous active requests.[*]
        // Until the server replies to this request, it can't read another,
        // so we might as well run the handler in this goroutine.
        // [*] Not strictly true: HTTP pipelining. We could let them all process
        // in parallel even if their responses need to be serialized.
        // But we're not going to implement HTTP pipelining because it
        // was never deployed in the wild and the answer is HTTP/2.
        serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
        w.cancelCtx()
        if c.hijacked() {
            return
        }
        w.finishRequest()
        if !w.shouldReuseConnection() {
            if w.requestBodyLimitHit || w.closedRequestBodyEarly() {
                c.closeWriteAndWait()
            }
            return
        }
        c.setState(c.rwc, StateIdle)
        c.curReq.Store((*response)(nil))

        if !w.conn.server.doKeepAlives() {
            // We're in shutdown mode. We might've replied
            // to the user without "Connection: close" and
            // they might think they can send another
            // request, but such is life with HTTP/1.1.
            return
        }

        if d := c.server.idleTimeout(); d != 0 {
            c.rwc.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(d))
            if _, err := c.bufr.Peek(4); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
        c.rwc.SetReadDeadline(time.Time{})
    }
}
```

and there, it calls `serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)`:

```
// serverHandler delegates to either the server's Handler or
// DefaultServeMux and also handles "OPTIONS *" requests.
type serverHandler struct {
    srv *Server
}

func (sh serverHandler) ServeHTTP(rw ResponseWriter, req *Request) {
    handler := sh.srv.Handler
    if handler == nil {
        handler = DefaultServeMux
    }
    if req.RequestURI == "*" && req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        handler = globalOptionsHandler{}
    }
    handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

which is the function wrapper that then calls `ServeHTTP` for the corresponding handler set before:

```
func (sh serverHandler) ServeHTTP(rw ResponseWriter, req *Request) {
    handler := sh.srv.Handler
    if handler == nil {
        handler = DefaultServeMux
    }
    if req.RequestURI == "*" && req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        handler = globalOptionsHandler{}
    }
    handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got to know about Handler